# Modify settings "option" value based on if / else statements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've built a small "discounts" jquery plugin which changes the price of products. The plugin modifies all prices based on the discounted percentage value set in the options and also excludes certain ID's, which again can be set in the options.

Here is a working Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/panoply/y2qw3ncu/3/

I now need to add additional discounts values based on certain product ID's but i'm not sure how to proceed. To better explain what I am trying to achieve (I understand this is incorrect, but for an example):

```
$('.price').TTprices({
    if (products: ['a1','a2']) 
    {
        discount: 10
    } 
    else if (products: ['a3'])
    {
        discount: 20
    }  
    else {
        discount: 50
    }  
});
```

I would of course add this to the plugin and not where I am calling it in above example, but I am a loss of how to achieve something like this in a fluid and friendly way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a configuration object like this:

```
$('.price').TTprices({
    discount: 50,
    products: [{
        id: 'a1',
        extraDiscount: 10
    }, {
        id: 'a2'
    }, {
        id: 'a3',
        extraDiscount: 30
    }],
});
```

Then, in your plugin, iterate over these discounts:

```
return this.each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $value = $this.contents()[0].textContent;
    var $price = parseFloat($value);
    var $discount = settings.discount;
    var $total = $price - ($price * $discount);
    var $productID = $this.data('product-id');
    var $products = (settings.products);
    var $saleTag = $this.find("span[data-badge='priceline']"); // Sale Tag

    $this.html(function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < $products.length; i++) {
            var item = $products[i];
            if (item.id == $productID) {
                if ($value >= (settings.threshold)) {
                    var extraDiscount = item.extraDiscount ? item.extraDiscount : 0;
                    $discount = ($discount + extraDiscount) / 100;
                    $total = $price - ($price * $discount);
                    $saleTag.html(($discount * 100) + '% OFF');
                    return $this.html().replace($value, $total.toFixed(2) + " ");
                }
            }
        }

        $saleTag.empty();
        return $this.html();
    });

});
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/skaparate/gc13vnqb/

**Update**

To fix your code, simply change the inner `for` loop iteration `index name`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < $products.length; i++) {

    var item = $products[i];
    var itemIds = $products[i].id;

    // The $productID need to be an array (My issue is here)
    // Here you cannot use var i, since it's defined in the parent loop

    var inArray = false;
    for (var j = 0; j < itemIds.length; j++) {
        if (itemIds[j] == $productID) {
            inArray = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Other code ....
}
```

Comment: Creative fix! appreciate it. +1!!

Comment: What about making the `$productID` an array?

Comment: You would make $this.data('product-id') an array? You can make anything out of Javascript :P

Comment: Could update your answer? I'm having such a hard time trying to figure out how to get it working. Here is what i've tried turning $this.data.('product') into an array: https://jsfiddle.net/panoply/2cqv9ar7/2/ but now calling it a second time with different extraDiscount it wont show.

Comment: Please fix formatting.  You have code spilling outside of the first code-block.